# LOG4j2 - Multiple files are saved again at the end of the process

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I've been dealing with this problem for a long time, and couldn't find a solution.
I have a batch process, that consists of multiple processes, each one logging into its own file.

**Problem**

Files are saved *again* at the end of the process, resulting in files being saved with the same timestamp.

**Possible solution**

I've tried to lookup method for manual closing of the FileAppender after process is done, but didnt find anything. I am looking for something like `logger.close()`

**Config file - log4j2.xml (only one appender, all others are configured by the same template)**

`<Appenders>`

```
<File name="processX" filename="log/processX.${filePattern}.log" immediateFlush="false" 
      append="false" createOnDemand="true">
    <PatternLayout>
        <LevelPatternSelector defaultPattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c %5p: %m%n">
            <PatternMatch key="WARN" pattern="%p %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c %m%n"/>
            <PatternMatch key="ERROR" pattern="%p %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c %m%n"/>
        </LevelPatternSelector>
    </PatternLayout>
</File>
```

`<Loggers>`

```
<Logger name="log_processX" level="debug">
    <AppenderRef ref="processX"/>
</Logger>
```

Note that I've tried using `createOnDemand="true"` which works, but all files are saved again after termination of JVM, thus rewriting the timestamp of creation (update)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I've found the answer. After calling `LogManager.getLogger("logger_name")`, you can close all resources **(ALL!)** by `LogManager.shutdown()`

Note that this will close all your logger instances, so you have to call `LogManager.getLogger("logger_name")` again after closing.